# How can I assign a result of a query to a variable in nodejs using sqlite?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I want to save the result of a query into a variable called isbnValid in order to check if the isbn is in the database. I want to have an error message if there is no such isbn in the database.

I have the following logic:

```
router.get('/delete', (req, res, next) => {
    var isbnValid 
    db.serialize(function() {
    db.run('SELECT isbn FROM books WHERE isbn=?', req.query.isbn, function(err,rows) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            setValue(rows)
        }
    })})

    function setValue(value) {
        isbnValid = value;
        console.log(isbnValid)
    }

        if ('isbn' in req.query /*&& req.query.isbn == isbnValid*/) {
            db.run('DELETE FROM books WHERE isbn = ?', req.query.isbn)
            console.log(isbnValid)
            res.redirect('/');
            res.end();
            }

        else {
        
            console.log("Error")
            console.log(isbnValid)
            res.render("500")
            res.end()       
        
        }})
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work and my isbnValid variable is still undefined.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

did you try console log "value" in your code? Do you get something back? Also you might try to give your variable a starting value of "null".

Comment: Unfortunately also undefined and setting the variable to null beforehand doesn't help either. Thanks anyway

Comment: So I looked onto your database request and that dose not make sense to me. Do you want to get the whole row of the result of your isbn? Try using: db.run('SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn=?', req.query.isbn, function(err,rows) {

Comment: No I just want to get the ISBN.